# GIF animation plays extremely fast in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, animated-gif

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import common.ResourcesToAccess;

public class RecordingStartingThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon reel = new ImageIcon("src/images/reel.GIF");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(reel);
        reel.setImageObserver(label);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RecordingStartingThread().start();
    } 
}
```

**Issue:**  GIF plays extremely fast.

**Question:**  How do I make sure that GIF plays at a normal speed?

Comment: This should be split into 2 separate questions.  Which one do you want answered this ..question?

Comment: Tough choice... 2nd one.

Comment: You now have an answer for the 1st.  Stick with that question this time around.

Comment: Swing GUIs should be created and modified on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for GIF speed playback - I've encountered this problem too. If I remember correctly this was caused by the "default" (or not provided?) value for frame rate in GIF file. Some web browsers "overrided" that frame rate so that GIF played correctly.

As a result I created a class that converts GIF (read GIF -> write GIF) and give frame rate provided by the user. `com.madgag.gif.fmsware.AnimatedGifEncoder` class is an external library that I link to the project via Maven: `animated-gif-lib-1.0.jar`

```
public final class GIFUtils {

private GIFUtils() {
}

public static List<BufferedImage> extractFrames(String filePath) throws IOException {
    return extractFrames(new File(filePath));
}

public static List<BufferedImage> extractFrames(File file) throws IOException {
    List<BufferedImage> imgs = new LinkedList<BufferedImage>();
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("GIF").next();
    ImageInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        reader.setInput(in);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        int count = reader.getNumImages(true);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Node tree = reader.getImageMetadata(i).getAsTree("javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0");
            int x = Integer.valueOf(tree.getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes()
                    .getNamedItem("imageLeftPosition").getNodeValue());
            int y = Integer.valueOf(tree.getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes()
                    .getNamedItem("imageTopPosition").getNodeValue());
            BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
            if(img == null) {
                img = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth() + x, image.getHeight() + y,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
            }

            Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
            ImageUtils.setBestRenderHints(g);
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
            imgs.add(ImageUtils.copy(img));
        }
    }
    finally {
        if(in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
    return imgs;
}

public static void writeGif(List<BufferedImage> images, File gifFile, int millisForFrame)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedImage firstImage = images.get(0);
    int type = firstImage.getType();

    ImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(gifFile);

    // create a gif sequence with the type of the first image, 1 second
    // between frames, which loops continuously
    GifSequenceWriter writer = new GifSequenceWriter(output, type, 100, false);

    // write out the first image to our sequence...
    writer.writeToSequence(firstImage);
    for(int i = 1; i < images.size(); i++) {
        BufferedImage nextImage = images.get(i);
        writer.writeToSequence(nextImage);
    }

    writer.close();
    output.close();
}

public static Image createGif(List<BufferedImage> images, int millisForFrame) {
    AnimatedGifEncoder g = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(5 * 1024 * 1024);
    g.start(out);
    g.setDelay(millisForFrame);
    g.setRepeat(1);
    for(BufferedImage i : images) {
        g.addFrame(i);
    }
    g.finish();
    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bytes);
}
```

And `GifSequenceWriter` looks like this:

```
public class GifSequenceWriter {
    protected ImageWriter gifWriter;
    protected ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam;
    protected IIOMetadata imageMetaData;

    public GifSequenceWriter(ImageOutputStream outputStream, int imageType, int timeBetweenFramesMS,
            boolean loopContinuously) throws IIOException, IOException {
        gifWriter = getWriter();
        imageWriteParam = gifWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(imageType);

        imageMetaData = gifWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageTypeSpecifier, imageWriteParam);

        String metaFormatName = imageMetaData.getNativeMetadataFormatName();

        IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) imageMetaData.getAsTree(metaFormatName);

        IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(root, "GraphicControlExtension");

        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorFlag", "FALSE");
        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("delayTime", Integer.toString(timeBetweenFramesMS / 10));
        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorIndex", "0");

        IIOMetadataNode commentsNode = getNode(root, "CommentExtensions");
        commentsNode.setAttribute("CommentExtension", "Created by MAH");

        IIOMetadataNode appEntensionsNode = getNode(root, "ApplicationExtensions");

        IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");

        child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
        child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");

        int loop = loopContinuously ? 0 : 1;

        child.setUserObject(new byte[] { 0x1, (byte) (loop & 0xFF), (byte) (loop >> 8 & 0xFF) });
        appEntensionsNode.appendChild(child);

        imageMetaData.setFromTree(metaFormatName, root);

        gifWriter.setOutput(outputStream);

        gifWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
    }

    public void writeToSequence(RenderedImage img) throws IOException {
        gifWriter.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(img, null, imageMetaData), imageWriteParam);
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        gifWriter.endWriteSequence();
    }

    private static ImageWriter getWriter() throws IIOException {
        Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("gif");
        if(!iter.hasNext()) {
            throw new IIOException("No GIF Image Writers Exist");
        }
        return iter.next();
    }

    private static IIOMetadataNode getNode(IIOMetadataNode rootNode, String nodeName) {
        int nNodes = rootNode.getLength();
        for(int i = 0; i < nNodes; i++) {
            if(rootNode.item(i).getNodeName().compareToIgnoreCase(nodeName) == 0) {
                return (IIOMetadataNode) rootNode.item(i);
            }
        }
        IIOMetadataNode node = new IIOMetadataNode(nodeName);
        rootNode.appendChild(node);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this problem is to just create a .gif file which is "well-formed", i.e. contains the appropriate frame rate. This can be achieved with the help of various online converters, just google "gif speed changer".