# Gif image display ugly in JLabel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm not so new to Java but I'm having a weird prolem with `JLabel`.

**My Problem:**

The gif image displayed in `JLabel` is too fast, laggy and ugly. But looping, animation... are Ok

**What I have tried:**

- Open that gif on Chrome browser: Its displayed smoothly
- Change another gif: Its still too fast when display on JLable and smooth on Chrome.
- Use Jlable in JPanel, Dialog, JFrame.
- Google.
- Youtube: found a video displays a gif and its look good not like my app.
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPL7OfS_V9Y

**My Code:**

```
jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/waiting.gif")));
```

Could someone please give me an advice?.

Thank you.

Comment: I followed some tutorial on the internet and my gif still displays too fast.

Comment: What are the width and height of your gif? Is it a small image that is being enlarged when displayed in the JLabel? Can you add a link to the image?

Comment: @Barzee: Thank you for your advice. I try with many gifs, from big to small, from long to wide. Its just displayed too fast (like a flashing light and I can not see the images clearly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GIF animation plays extremely fast in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054555/gif-animation-plays-extremely-fast-in-jframe) sounds pretty much like your problem. You may need an external library to control the play speed.

Comment: Thank you. I'm taking a look at it now. I will responde if it works or not.

Comment: I followed that post, My gif is played in custom speed, but my background image is changed to black.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. But does myLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE); help? Which color did you expect rather than black?

Comment: My gif's backgroud is transparent. So I don't want it to be black like that. :(

Comment: setForeground does not have any effect the gif image.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the image and check that the foreground is transparent.
Also change the jLabel foreground to white or equal to the main-background where it is inserted.